# MySQL datetime: insert a date with timezone offset

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I tried to insert a timestamp into 'dates' with:

```
INSERT INTO dates VALUES (4, "2011-10-04 12:58:36 -0600")
```

4 is just an ID. In the table it is inserted as:

```
2011-10-04 12:58:36 or 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

So my problem is, that the time difference -0600 is lost. How can I insert it, too?

Comment: MySQL date/datetime fields don't support timezones. They're just raw dates and time values. You'll have to store the timezone seperately in another field. Best bet is to store all your dates/times as UTC values, then adjust as necessary upon retrieval.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use SUBSTR() to chop it off and CONVERT_TZ() to convert it.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Something like this

```
INSERT INTO table_name  CONVERT_TZ(SUBSTR('2011-10-04 12:58:36 -0600',1,19),'+00:00',SUBSTR('2011-10-04 12:58:36 -0600',20));
```

Comment: ":" is required in timezone offset, space is not allowed. `CONVERT_TZ(SUBSTR('2011-10-04 12:58:36 -06:00',1,19),'+00:00',SUBSTR('2011-10-04 12:58:36 -06:00',21))`

Comment: RFC 3339 defines the format for these timezone offset dates and there is no space before the offset and there is a 'T' separating the date and time parts.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339#section-5.8