# MySQL insert to DATETIME: is it safe to use ISO::8601 format?

Tags: mysql, datetime, iso8601

In our project we use Zend Framework Model generator, which produces something like this to set the properties that are stored in DB (MySQL) as DATETIME fields:

```
public function setObjectDatetime($data) {
  if (! $data instanceof Zend_Date) { ... some conversion code ... }
  $this->objectDatetime = $data->toString(Zend_Date::ISO_8601);
}
```

So the ISO::8601 formatted string ('2012-06-15T18:33:00+03:00' for example) is what actually is stored as a property.

The problem arises when we try to `save` this model, and pass this string to MySQL (version 5.5.16): it raise the warning, but still inserts/updates the corresponding row with a correct result. It's easy to check that the issue is caused by MySQL, and not some drivers' behaviour: just issue such query as...

```
UPDATE table_name SET datetime_field = '2012-06-15T18:33:00+03:00' WHERE id = 1;
```

... and the result will be `1 row affected, 1 warning`, with

`1264 | Out of range value for column 'dt' at row 1`

warning (shown by `SHOW WARNINGS`).

To my amuzement, phpMyAdmin doesn't show any warnings at all; and all the server-side code processed this query as a solid one. )

So the question is: should we really reformat what we store in our Model into another string format ('YY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', for example?) Or is it just some weird behavior of MySQL that will be fixed sooner or later?

Comment: Especially in mysql 5.7 you'll get an error doing that.
"Y-m-d H:i:s"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like the short answer to this question is "No, it's not safe" - this conclusion follows a series of experiments with MySQL shell. Still would appreciate a more "theoretical" answer, though...

Apparently MySQL engine is (by default) pretty liberal in what it accepts as a Datetime literal even with `sql_mode` set to STRICT_ALL_TABLES : not only various separators are accepted, they may differ as well:

`INSERT INTO t(dt) VALUES('2012-01,03.04:05@06'); -- Query OK, 1 row affected`

Besides, if the string is too short, it will be padded with zeroes... but there might be surprises:

`INSERT INTO t(dt) VALUES('2012011'); -- 2020-12-01 01:00:00 is what's inserted`

The sad thing is that the string too long (when the last parsable digit is followed by something other than whitespace) will be considered an invalid value in strict mode:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO t(dt) VALUES('2012-06-27T05:25Z');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2012-06-27T05:25Z' for column 'dt' at row 1
mysql> INSERT INTO t(dt) VALUES('2012-06-27T05:25');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)
```

In the traditional mode parsing is even more relaxed - but not more precise; besides, the strings that are considered incorrect in the strict mode will give sort of 'silent warnings', though operations will succeed:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO t(dt) VALUES('2012-06-27T05:25Z');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.10 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'dt' at row 1 |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT dt FROM t;
+---------------------+
| dt                  |
+---------------------+
| 2012-06-27 05:25:00 |
+---------------------+
```

The bottom line is that we had to rewrite some DAL-related code so that dates (and datetimes) are always sent to the DB in "normalized" form. I wonder why it's we who have to do it, and not Zend_Db developers. But that's another story, I suppose. )

Answer (score 5):

By default MySQL use ISO9075 format for datetime

> The possible values for the first and second arguments result in several possible format strings (for the specifiers used, see the table in the DATE_FORMAT() function description). ISO format refers to ISO 9075, not ISO 8601.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_get-format

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no way to store time offset information (the +03:00 at the end of your ISO 8601 string) in MySQL Date or Time types, so you're sort of on your own to find a solution.

One possible approach is to split the ISO 8601 string and store the offset in a char(5) column, though admittedly it would make it sort of difficult to work with. I suppose you could store the offset in a Time column, which might make date/time manipulations a little bit easier.

**EDIT**
I just stumbled upon [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) in the MySQL docs, which may be helpful.

Comment: I see your point, but the question is more about validity of the format itself. ) Actually Zend_Date converted all datetimes to the GMT ones in our case, so timezone offset in these strings was always +00:00. Anyway, thank you for your answer. )

Comment: It looks like the timezone offset is not parsed at all by MySQL: at least TIMESTAMP fields were updated with the same data whatever '+XX:00' I used. Sad.

Comment: Oh, ok, my misunderstanding - I thought the timezone info was important/necessary.

Comment: It is necessary if you are working across timezones. PS MySql by default when presented with data it can't convert does a best guessgoogle mysql strict for details

Comment: Found this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651409/mysql-datetime-insert-a-date-with-timezone-offset) illustrating the possible way of inserting the timezone info as well. But I suppose converting the datetime with the server-side (and considering all the datetime stored as GMT only) is a better approach...

Comment: Personally, a simpler method was to use Unix Epoch time then apply the  FROM_UNIXTIME() function on insert.