# ISO 8601 Timestamp for MySQL Database: MySQL Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime, phpmyadmin, iso8601

Error log:

> { [Error: Incorrect datetime value: '2012-08-24T17:29:11.683Z' for
>   column 'robot _refreshed_at' at row 1] number: 1292, sqlStateMarker:
>   '#',  sqlState: '22007', message: 'Incorrect datetime value:
>   \'2012-08-24T17:29:11.683Z\' for column \' robot_refreshed_at\' at row
>   1', sql: 'INSERT INTO users
>   (id,name,count_moments,count_likes,count_followers,rob
>   ot_refreshed_at,robot_count_followers) VALUES
>   (\'1834084\',\'NNNyingzi\',\'5\',\
>   '0\',\'0\',\'2012-08-24T17:29:11.683Z\',\'0\')', setMaxListeners:
>   [Function], emit: [Function], addListener: [Function], on: [Function],
>   once: [Function], removeListener: [Function], removeAllListeners:
>   [Function], listeners: [Function] }

I use this piece of code in my `Node.js`

```
  if s instanceof Date
         return s.toISOString()
```

and updated them in database.

The `SQL` insert expression follows:

```
     INSERT INTO users (id,name,count_moments,count_likes,count_followers,rob ot_refreshed_at,robot_count_followers) VALUES (\'1834084\',\'NNNyingzi\',\'5\',\ '0\',\'0\',\'2012-08-24T17:29:11.683Z\',\'0\')
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I just copied a table using `PHPMyAdmin` from a table in server.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated in [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) and [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` or `'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts. For example, `'2012-12-31 11:30:45'`, `'2012^12^31 11+30+45'`, `'2012/12/31 11*30*45'`, and `'2012@12@31 11^30^45'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'` or `'YYMMDDHHMMSS'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523091528'` and `'070523091528'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23 09:15:28'`, but `'071122129015'` is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part) and becomes `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` or `YYMMDDHHMMSS` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905132800` and `830905132800` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05 13:28:00'`.
>
> A [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) or [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. Although this fractional part is recognized, it is discarded from values stored into [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) or [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) columns. For information about fractional seconds support in MySQL, see [Section 11.3.6, “Fractional Seconds in Time Values”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fractional-seconds.html).

Your date literal of `'2012-08-24T17:29:11.683Z'` does not fit any of these formats; suggest you either—

- use instead the Node.js Date object's [`toLocaleFormat()`](http://nodemanual.org/0.6.10/js_doc/Date.html#Date.toLocaleFormat) method (be sure that the timezone of the MySQL connection matches that of Node.js's locale):

  ```
    if s instanceof Date
           return s.toLocaleFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  ```
- use the Node.js Date object's [`valueOf()`](http://nodemanual.org/0.6.10/js_doc/Date.html#Date.valueOf) method to obtain the time's value in *milliseconds* since the UNIX epoch, divide by `1000` (to get *seconds* since the UNIX epoch) and pass through MySQL's [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function.

Comment: Has it changed over different versions of `MySQL`? I am sure that on the server where I copied the table from is running properly.

Comment: @ComboZhc: Not to my knowledge.  Perhaps PHPMyAdmin formats the output for display in that way, but the format is not a valid MySQL datetime literal.  You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to perform conversions, if required.

Comment: If you have problems setting datetimes with millis and/or microseconds you can disable mysql strict mode (set sql_mode='')

Comment: toLocaleString() not supported by node, I wrote `s.toISOString().substr(0,19).replace('T',' ');` that may look horrible, but it is ok, always

Comment: @DanieleCruciani: just beware that that will always produce a literal in UTC whereas MySQL may understand it to be in the session’s timezone.  Best first set the session timezone to UTC to avoid any translation errors.

Comment: @eggyal I see, you mean something like `SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";` before. On the other hand I am using https://locutus.io/ because of speedup some migration, so date("Y-m-d H:i:s") will do it clearly. I tried also `s.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT')` for time is ok, but no date.

At the end `FROM_UNIXTIME()` and `Math.round(s.getTime()/1000)` is the better solution for me, at least it is clear and readable, and does not require so much resources

Comment: It is also worth noting that the `toLocaleFormat` method has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I find it on this link:

[MySQL insert to DATETIME: is it safe to use ISO::8601 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053941/mysql-insert-to-datetime-is-it-safe-to-use-iso8601-format)

It seems that inserting an ISO8601 timestamp is not safe. It depends on the parser of `MySQL`. Maybe different versions use different methods.

```
Date.prototype.format = (format) ->
  o = { 
    "(M+)" : this.getMonth()+1,
    "(d+)" : this.getDate(),
    "(h+)" : this.getHours(),
    "(m+)" : this.getMinutes(),
    "(s+)" : this.getSeconds(),
    "(q+)" : Math.floor((this.getMonth()+3)/3),
    "(S)" : this.getMilliseconds()
  } 
  if /(y+)/.test(format)
    format = format.replace(RegExp.$1, (this.getFullYear()+"").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length))
  for k, v of o
    if (new RegExp(k)).test(format)
       format = format.replace(RegExp.$1, if RegExp.$1.length == 1 then o[k] else ('00'+ o[k]).substr((''+ o[k]).length))
  return format
```

This piece code could provide `node.js` with the ability to format a `Date`