# Relax datetime validation on mysql 5.6.10 with my.cnf

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql2

My inserting format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`, but this is incorrect. I want to treat `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ` as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, how to set `my.cnf` or other solution?

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   Mysql2::Error: Incorrect datetime value: '2013-06-14T10:07:43Z' for column 'created_at' at row 1: INSERT into `products` (`id`,`description`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (1,'description','2013-06-14T10:07:43Z')
```

simular questions:

- [ISO 8601 Timestamp for MySQL Database: MySQL Incorrect datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114201/iso-8601-timestamp-for-mysql-database-mysql-incorrect-datetime-value)
- [MySQL insert to DATETIME: is it safe to use ISO::8601 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053941/mysql-insert-to-datetime-is-it-safe-to-use-iso8601-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You should never relax input restrictions. You can coerce the bad format into a valid one with something like

```
STR_TO_DATE('2013-06-14T10:07:43Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%sZ');
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't relax, and replace 'T' and 'Z'.