# What datatype to use for ISO 8601 dates?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, iso8601

I am redesigning a database that currently imports ISO 8601 dates in the format of `2012-10-27T07:30:38+00:00` into a varchar field. The current database is hosted on a MySQL 5.5 server.

In searching through documentation and various SO posts, I have not found a definitive answer on what datatype I should use in MySQL for this purpose. The closest post is:  [MySQL insert to DATETIME: is it safe to use ISO::8601 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053941/mysql-insert-to-datetime-is-it-safe-to-use-iso8601-format) where it provides a work around of sorts, however this is not a desirable option.

The MySQL documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html) does not say, and the only reference I can find on official documentation is located on page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

which states "The possible values for the first and second arguments result in several possible format strings (for the specifiers used, see the table in the DATE_FORMAT() function description). ISO format refers to ISO 9075, not ISO 8601."

Now the PostgreSQL documentation specifically mentions ISO8601 ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datetime-keywords.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html ) which leads me to my  question:

**Does MySQL correctly support ISO 8601, or should I consider a database with native support?**

--Edit--

Attempting to insert the example time stamp above into a datetime column gives the following error:

```
10:55:55    insert into test(date1) values('2012-10-27T07:30:38+00:00') Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2012-10-27T07:30:38+00:00' for column 'date1' at row 1 0.047 sec
```

Comment: Switching your database because of a date formatting issue seems a bit heavy-handed. Have you tried inserting values in your desired format? If so, what happened? MySQL is usually pretty relaxed in terms of what it will allow.

Comment: @tadman Not saying it isn't. I'm looking to do things properly this time around though. My preference is to stay with MySQL but use the proper datatypes.

Comment: Do **NOT** store timestamps in VARCHAR columns. Never. Use a native `timestamp` data type and do the formatting when displaying the data. Do **not** use a varchar for this

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` columns are semi-magical and shouldn't be used unless you need them. `DATETIME` is the generic date and time format, or `DATE` for date only.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hence this question :)

Comment: @tadman: the PostgreSQL `timestamp` datatype has no "magical" behaviour and matches the MySQL `datetime` data type (albeit with higher precision)

Comment: Another caveat is `TIMESTAMP` is more limited in terms of allowable times, and the first of these columns will automatically be set to the current time when a row is inserted unless a non-NULL value is explicitly supplied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not store date or timestamp values in a varchar column. You have no way of ensuring that a correct value is stored (no one prevents you from storing `2012-02-31 28:99:70` in there.

If you don't need the time part, use a `date` datatype (available in MySQL and PostgreSQL) if you do need the time use a `timestamp` (or `datetime` in MySQL) data type.

The formatting of the values should be done in your frontend or if you absolutely have to do it in SQL using e.g. to_char() (or the equivalent in MySQL) when retrieving the values.

Again: never store dates or timestamps in a varchar (just as you should never stored real numbers in a varchar column).

Here is the MySQL overview for date/time datatypes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

Here is the PostgreSQL overview for date7time datatypes: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

**Edit**

If you are concerned about the literal format. Both DBMS support the standard ANSI Date and Timestamp literals:

```
insert into some_table 
   (ts_column, date_column)
values
   (timestamp '2012-10-27T07:30:38+00:00', DATE '2012-12-30');
```

SQLFiddle for PostgreSQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cdd39/1

Note the keywords `timestamp` and `date` in front of the character literal.

**Edit 2**

It seems MySQL cannot *insert* such a value, although it *can* use that literal in a SELECT statement:

Comment: So to answer my original question: MySQL does not have a native datatype for expressing these values and in order to get them to insert correctly I need to massage the data first?

Comment: @RobertH: MySQL *does* have a native datatype to store timestamp: it's called `datetime`. Do not confuse storage with display.

Comment: If I use the datetime datatype I get the error in my edited post: `Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2012-10-27T07:30:38+00:00' for column 'date1' at row 1 0.047 sec` The problem is the `+00:00` section of the provided timestamps. If it was native I should not have to remove this from the timestamp.

Comment: @RobertH: what datatype is the column `date1`

Comment: date1 is datetime, I have also tried with timestamp with similar results

Comment: @RobertH: seems to be one of those MySQL "suprises". It can use such a timestamp literal in a SELECT Statement, but apparently not in an insert (so after all you might really be better off using PostgreSQL...)

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to look into this - I think I might bite the bullet and switch - too much of our data is date and time sensitive to play around with the data before it gets added.

Comment: @RobertH: PostgreSQL has a lot more advantages than just the better timestamp handling ;)

Answer (score 2):

Postgresql can handle that format:

without

```
select timestamp '2012-10-27T07:30:38+00:00';
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2012-10-27 07:30:38
```

or with time zone:

```
select timestamptz '2012-10-27T07:30:38+00:00';
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2012-10-27 05:30:38-02
```

Whereas MySQL seems to not care much about the time zone part:

```
create table t (ts timestamp);

insert into t (ts) values
('2012-10-27T07:30:38+03:00'),
('2012-10-27T07:30:38-02:00');

select * from t;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2012-10-27 07:30:38 |
| 2012-10-27 07:30:38 |
+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format, "YYYY-MM-DD", is what MySQL emits internally when displaying date values and it can import them just the same.

These are preferable to "American style" dates like "MM/DD/YY" where there's too much ambiguity to be automatically resolved.

ISO 9075 appears to refer to the entirety of the SQL standard, not a specific date format, though the standard itself does have standard formatting for dates and times.

Comment: I apologize tadman, I thought I had placed an example date/time string in my post, but I had not. Can you please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just another advantage of using datetime or timestamp for storing.
In phpMyAdmin or phpPgAdmin the value is displayed as a string e.g. 2015-01-22 11:13:42. So it's much easier to find a date as if it's stored as a varchar or int.

And I think it's important what timezone the server has.
I've see that a timestamp in MySql doesn't display microseconds.
I know MySQL use UTC-Time for timestamp and datetime-fields.
So provide the values as a UTC-timestamp.