# Database Error:00' for column 'date' at row 1

Tags: php, apache, anchor-cms

I have just finished installing anchor-cms but when I go to view the admin page or the homepage I get the following output

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Database Error:00' for column 'date' at row 1


SQL: INSERT INTO `sessions` (`id`, `date`, `data`) values (?, ?, ?)
Location:

/Library/WebServer/Documents/anchor/system/database/connection.php on line 128
Stack Trace:

#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/anchor/system/database/query.php(254): System\Database\Connection->execute('INSERT INTO `se...', Array)
#1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/anchor/system/session/database.php(42): System\Database\Query->insert(Array)
#2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/anchor/system/session/payload.php(78): System\Session\Database->save(Array, Array, false)
#3 [internal function]: System\Session\Payload->save()
#4 /Library/WebServer/Documents/anchor/system/session.php(58): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /Library/WebServer/Documents/anchor/system/bootstrap.php(124): System\Session::__callStatic('save', Array)
#6 /Library/WebServer/Documents/anchor/system/bootstrap.php(124): System\Session::save()
#7 /Library/WebServer/Documents/anchor/index.php(33): require('/Library/WebSer...')
#8 {main}
```

**Here is my connection.php file**

```
<?php namespace System\Database;

/**
 * Nano
 *
 * Lightweight php framework
 *
 * @package     nano
 * @author      k. wilson
 * @link        http://madebykieron.co.uk
 */

use System\Config;
use PDO, PDOStatement, PDOException, Exception;

class Connection {

    public $pdo, $config, $queries = array();

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, $config) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function transaction($callback) {
        $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

        // After beginning the database transaction, we will call the callback
        // so that it can do its database work. If an exception occurs we'll
        // rollback the transaction and re-throw back to the developer.
        try {
            call_user_func($callback);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->pdo->rollBack();

            throw $e;
        }

        $this->pdo->commit();
    }

    public function query($sql, $bindings = array()) {
        $sql = trim($sql);

        list($statement, $result) = $this->execute($sql, $bindings);

        // The result we return depends on the type of query executed against the
        // database. On SELECT clauses, we will return the result set, for update
        // and deletes we will return the affected row count.
        if(stripos($sql, 'select') === 0 or stripos($sql, 'show') === 0) {
            return $this->fetch($statement, Config::get('database.fetch'));
        }
        elseif(stripos($sql, 'update') === 0 or stripos($sql, 'delete') === 0) {
            return $statement->rowCount();
        }
        // For insert statements that use the "returning" clause, which is allowed
        // by database systems such as Postgres, we need to actually return the
        // real query result so the consumer can get the ID.
        elseif (stripos($sql, 'insert') === 0 and stripos($sql, 'returning') !== false) {
            return $this->fetch($statement, Config::get('database.fetch'));
        }
        else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function first($sql, $bindings = array()) {
        list($statement, $result) = $this->execute($sql, $bindings);

        if($result) return $statement->fetch(Config::get('database.fetch'));
    }

    public function column($sql, $bindings = array()) {
        list($statement, $result) = $this->execute($sql, $bindings);

        if($result) return $statement->fetchColumn();
    }

    public function type($var) {
        if(is_null($var)) {
            return PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        }

        if(is_int($var)) {
            return PDO::PARAM_INT;
        }

        if(is_bool($var)) {
            return PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        }

        return PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }

    public function execute($sql, $bindings = array()) {
        // Each database operation is wrapped in a try / catch so we can wrap
        // any database exceptions in our custom exception class, which will
        // set the message to include the SQL and query bindings.
        try {
            $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

            // bind paramaters by data type
            // test key to see if we have to bump the index by one
            $zerobased = (strpos(key($bindings), ':') === 0) ? false : true;

            foreach($bindings as $index => $bind) {
                $key = $zerobased ? ($index + 1) : $index;

                $statement->bindValue($key, $bind, $this->type($bind));
            }

            $start = microtime(true);

            $result = $statement->execute();

            $this->queries[] = array($statement->queryString, $bindings);
        }
        // If an exception occurs, we'll pass it into our custom exception
        // and set the message to include the SQL and query bindings so
        // debugging is much easier on the developer.
        catch(PDOException $exception) {
            $message = explode(':', $exception->getMessage());

            $error = '<strong>Database Error:</strong>' . end($message) . str_repeat("\n", 3) .
                '<strong>SQL: </strong>' . $sql;

            $exception = new Exception($error, 0, $exception);

            throw $exception;
        }

        return array($statement, $result);
    }

    protected function fetch($statement, $style) {
        // If the fetch style is "class", we'll hydrate an array of PHP
        // stdClass objects as generic containers for the query rows,
        // otherwise we'll just use the fetch style value.
        if($style === PDO::FETCH_CLASS) {
            return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'stdClass');
        }
        else {
            return $statement->fetchAll($style);
        }
    }

}
```

**Second Error**

```
Database Error: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2013-02-19T06:47:59+00:00' for column 'date' at row 1
```

Comment: That error message is apparently not helping. Can you change the line `$message = explode(':', $exception->getMessage());` to `$message = explode(':', $exception->getMessage(), 2);` and then retry to get the actual error message, which might help (It is probably a problem with the date format).

Comment: @vstm I updated the error in my question, it is a date problem, How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: technically this is not an answer ;)

Apparently the anchor-CMS uses the ISO 8601-format to store (at least) the session-date, which is apparently [not safe to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053941/mysql-insert-to-datetime-is-it-safe-to-use-iso8601-format), especially when the "strict mode" is active!

I think for the moment it's probably the best to disable the [strict mode of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html). If you don't "own" the SQL-Server you can disable the strict mode for a single session.

You can do that by editing system/database.php starting at line 51. Change the following lines from

```
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.6', '<=')) {
    $options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = 'SET NAMES ' . $config['charset'];
}
```

to

```
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.6', '<=')) {
    $options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = 'SET NAMES ' . $config['charset']
        . ', sql_mode=\'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES\'';
} else {
    $options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = 'SET sql_mode=\'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES\'';
}
```

I think that should work until anchor-CMS uses the correct dates (I probably make a pull-request for that this evening after work).