# MySQL: Incorrect Date Value

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am parsing an xml file that has following data structure:

```
  <row Id="253858" UserId="40883" Name="Scholar" Date="2009-03-08T01:52:32.570" />
  <row Id="253860" UserId="19483" Name="Supporter" Date="2009-03-08T01:57:31.733" />
  <row Id="253861" UserId="74951" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2009-03-08T02:02:32.390" />
```

I used a ruby script to parse this data and insert them into a mysql database. Here is how my data table looks like:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| user_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| name    | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

This xml file has large number of records and until the parser gets to 3rd record I don't get any error and all the data get parse correctly and insert into the table:

```
| 253857 |   23658 | Critic             | 2009-03-08 01:52:32 |
| 253858 |   40883 | Scholar            | 2009-03-08 01:52:33 |
| 253860 |   19483 | Supporter          | 2009-03-08 01:57:32 |
+--------+---------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

But when we get to the record with `row Id="253861"` I get the following mysql error:

```
load.rb:21:in `execute': Incorrect datetime value: '2009-03-08T02:02:32.390' for column 'created' at row 1 (Mysql::Error)
    from load.rb:21:in `on_start_element'
    from load.rb:133:in `parse'
    from load.rb:133:in `<main>'
```

incase if you need the ruby method that insert records:

```
  def on_start_element(element, attributes)
    if element == 'row'
      @st.execute(attributes['Id'], attributes['UserId'], attributes['Name'], attributes['Date'])
    end
  end
end
```

I don't think this is related to script, because I extracted the record from xml file and tried to insert directly into my mysql table and I got the following error:

```
mysql> insert into badge values(253861,74951,'Autobiographer','2009-03-08T02:02:32.390');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2009-03-08T02:02:32.390' for column 'created' at row 1
```

I also tried to insert the record that is after the above record in the xml file and I got the same results:

```
mysql> insert into badge values(253862,49628,'Teacher','2009-03-08T02:12:30.807');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2009-03-08T02:12:30.807' for column 'created' at row 1
```

So something in that date string makes mysql unhappy. What I couldn't figure out is that date and previous records that has the same date structure didn't have any problem. Hope I have explain the problem clear with information.

Comment: @bjhaid But as OP said, other worked, then why not with this reported one ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I edited the question... tried the record which is right after the troubled one.. got the same error.

Comment: @ArupRakshit read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053941/mysql-insert-to-datetime-is-it-safe-to-use-iso8601-format

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon parse the time from `iso1806` to a regular ruby time, using `Time.new(attributes['Date']).to_s` instead of `attributes['Date']`

Comment: @bjhaid i am new to ruby do i need to do `require Time`?

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon `Time` is in ruby core so you do not need to require `Time`, if this works for you let me know so I can post it as an answer

Comment: @bjhaid it didn't work. it gave me following error, `load.rb:21:in execute: Incorrect datetime value: '2008-01-01 00:00:00 -0600' for column 'created' at row 1 (Mysql::Error)` That record doesn't exist in the xml file. I bet time got converted into some strange value so it didn't even insert the first record.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47099/discussion-between-bjhaid-and-find-missing-semicolon)

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon I updated my answer, as `Time.new` is returning the first day of the year and not the correct date so `DateTime.parse` should be used instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you said you insert dates in a couple of places I would suggest you write and helper method to do date conversions that you can reuse everywhere you need to insert dates

```
require 'date'
def iso8601_to_mysql_datetime(date)
  DateTime.parse(date).to_time.strftime("%F %T")
end

iso8601_to_mysql_datetime('2009-03-08T02:02:32.390')
=> "2009-03-08 02:02:32"
```

NOTE: The above converts a `ISO8601` into a string that MySQL understands
MySQL date and time literal documentation can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: Though Time.new gave first date it did work (but wrong) but after the change with `DateTime.parse` its complaining on following: `2009-03-08 02:02:32` by complaining `Incorrect datetime value: '2009-03-08 02:02:32'`

Comment: also I realized prior to parse we have following: `2009-03-08T02:02:32.390` but some how `390` doens't have any effect on the parsed string. I found following: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48704/mysql-5-6-datetime-incorrect-datetime-value-2013-08-25t1700000000-with-er

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon you can use call `to_time` on the `DateTime` object and that gives you a `Time` object that behaves well, see update

Comment: Thanks, running it with the latest change. I guess I might have to change how I create the TIMESTAMP column to accept the miliseconds..? otherwise it will drop it i guess.